# What is the difference between Yakuza 0 and Yakuza 6?

Tags: version-differences, yakuza-0, yakuza-6-the-song-of-life

Sometimes I see *Ryu Ga Gotoku 6* (an opus of *Yakuza*). Interested by the game I decided to see if I could order it, but the only one available is *Yakuza 0.* I quite don't understand what's the link between those two games. Is *Yakuza 0* an American edition of *Ryu Ga Gotoku 6* or another game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yakuza 0 and Yakuza 6 are two separate games simply put the major difference between the two is that Yakuza 0 is a prequel to the entire series which takes place before Yakuza 1. Yakuza 6 will be the most current game in the Yakuza series taking place after Yakuza 5. So yes both games are completely separate games.

Comment: Ok... So it just means that we are a game late compared to Asia ?

Comment: Yeah we always have been with the Yakuza series since Japan doesn't think the rest of the world likes the series for some reason. Yakuza 6 just came out in Japan on the 8th so that game is brand new for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response ! It's a lot clearer for me now :) So I'll start with Yakuza 0, do the other games and patiently wait for the 6 ^^

Comment: I hope you enjoy the ride, the Yakuza series is one of my favorite open world franchises out there.